# Oracle GRANT ROLE error

Tags: oracle, role, permissions

I am trying to apply a role to a user and getting this error: `SQL Error: ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege`. Here is where I created the role, which worked fine logged in as SYSTEM.

```
    CREATE ROLE LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE SESSION TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE VIEW TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE ANY INDEX TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT SELECT ON BASEBALL.MASTER TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT SELECT ON BASEBALL.BATTING TO LahmanDBDev;
    GRANT SELECT ON BASEBALL.FIELDING TO LahmanDBDev;
```

Then I went on to create the user and grant the role to it, the second statement here where I grant the role is where I get the error:

```
    CREATE USER BudSelig
    IDENTIFIED BY BudSelig;

    GRANT ROLE LahmanDBDev
    TO BudSelig;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
   GRANT LahmanDBDev
   TO BudSelig;
```

Comment: Thanks, feeling pretty dumb right now but i knew it was something simple.